# Is there a way to convert textbox value and assign to php variable?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

My goal is to get some of the value from ajax data to assign in php variable. As you can see the ajax code below, i could pass the value through a class (`edit_id`). How to put the value from the textbox to a php variable?

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ URL::route('test') }}",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
        data: { "camp_id" : camp_id },
        success: function(data){
          if(data.data.success){
                $('#edit_id').val(data.data.success.id);
                $('#edit_desc').val(data.data.success.description);
                console.log(data.data.success.id); // this will output the id eg. 1
                console.log(data.data.success.description); // this will output the description eg. hello world
          }
        }
});
```

**View**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_id" name="id"> //will diplay textbox with value
```

Comment: I think you have double `edit_id` ID, check your html source code

Comment: Checked, does not contain any duplications

Comment: What do you want? To send the server the value of `edit_id`?

Comment: @חייםפרידמן i already mentioned it in the question above...assumed the ajax is successes

Comment: Are you familiar with html forms and how they send data back to server?

Comment: @azerafati i wouldnt say im very familiar with it...im know well about it

Comment: Taking it a step back, what are you planning on doing with the php variable after you've assigned the value to it?

Comment: to view it as a title of the page

Comment: anyone still have ideas...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first in your js file get the value of textbox using jquery .val() method and store it in javaScript variale. Then using AJAX post method you can pass it in your controller and can store it in php variable.

Ex. in your JS file

```
$(document).on('click','#payment',function(){
         var user_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              dataType:"json",
              url:"/payment",
              data:{
                user_id:user_id,
                type:type,
                amount:amount,
                remarks:remarks,
                _token:token
              },
              success:function(data){
                if(data.type=="success"){
                  $('#amount').val('');
                }
        }
      });
        return false;
    });
```

in your controller

```
public function addPost(Request $request){

                $title = request('title');
                $id = request('id');

        }
```